# Accepting a serialized form from jquery in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

In asp.net mvc it's pretty easy to receive a form collection in a ajax page webmethod like:

```
public bool AddSomething(FormCollection form)
{
   return true;
}
```

How do I receive serialized data in an asp.net page method:

```
  [WebMethod]
  public static string AddSomething(??)
  {
     //...
     return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure what you are asking about but if you are talking about how to send form data in serialize way using ajax then you can try this...

```
 url='your url'
    $.post(url,$('#formId').serialize(), function(responseValue) {
                        alert(responseValue);
    });
```

**updated:**

```
[WebMethod]
  public static string AddSomething()
  {
    string foo = Request["form element name"];//example
     return true;
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I understand how to serialize, but what PARAMETER is needed in the page webmethod to receive the form. i.e.  [WebMethod]
  public static string AddSomething(WHAT GOES HERE)
  {}

Comment: i am not well aware about asp.net but i think by using request object you can retrieve the form values in your method..see updated answer